# How can I set the URL for a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In a servlet I would just do

```
@WebServlet("/myURL")
```

But how would I do that with a JSP page?

Comment: do u want forward/redirect to url from jsp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like any servlet, you can map a particular URL-pattern to a JSP.

Simply add this snippet in your deployment descriptor

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fooBar</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/foo.jsp</jsp-file> <!-- Your JSP. Must begin with '/' -->
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fooBar</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bar</url-pattern> <!-- Any URL you want here -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

There is no facility to have annotations inside the JSP so if you don't want to make an entry inside the web.xml and work purely with annotations, you have a work around to make a sevlet that simply forwards the `RequestDispatcher` to the JSP and you can annotate this servlet with the URL that you want.

```
@WebServlet("/bar") //your URL pattern
public class DummyServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/foo.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. By the way, do you think there is any advantage to using the second method?

Comment: Both of the methods are more or less doing the same thing. IMO, the first method will be a bit fast in response since the jsp is directly mapped with the URL-pattern. Where-as in the second method, when you type `http://someurl/context/bar` , the servlet is first invoked which in turn re-directs to jsp. I think it will be a matter of negligible milliseconds. Besides that , the second method is viable in the case that you don't want any servlet entry in the deployment descriptor at all.

Comment: What is the deployment descriptor?

Comment: the `web.xml` file